# How to create a new magento catalog

Tags: magento, catalog

Magento comes with a root catalog after installation. the concept is under one root catalog you are free to create/add as many categories and subcategories as you like...but after searching I do not find a way to create/add aother catalog which is parallel and independent to the root catalog in structure. Is it possible? or any extension can do such job?

Answer (score 1):

**The Correct Way to Create a New Root Category**

**Step 1. Create a new root category**

```
- From the Admin panel, select Catalog > Manage Categories.
- In the upper-left of the Manage Categories page, click the Add Root Category button.
- In the Name field, type in the name of the root category.
- Set Is Active to Yes.
- On the Display Settings tab, and set Is Anchor to Yes.
- Click the Save Category button.
```

**Step 2. Create the subcategories within the new root category**

```
- From the Manage Categories page, in the category tree on thel left, click to highlight the new root category.
- Click the Add Subcategory button.
- Give the subcategory a Name and set Is Active to Yes.
- Click the Save Category button.
```

**Step 3. Link the new root category to your store.**

```
- From the Admin panel, select System > Manage Stores.
- From the Manage Stores page, click any one of the Main Store links to edit your store.
- Change Root Category to the new root category.
- Click the Save Store button.
```

Comment: @Divya. Thank you for help. I tried creating a new catalog, but that is not what I want, the new catalog need to be assigned to different store....What I want is two catalog in one store, for example, I have two type of things-- products and services. Also the newly created catalog is not displayed in frontend...

Answer (score 0):

Spark,it is possiable to create another root category in magento.

```
Step1:Please refresh the catagory

Step2: Donot click Root category

Step3: Just click on Add root category
```

Now ,new root category is created